# Async loading of Visualforce Custom Components

Tags: visualforce-component, javascript-remoting

I have a VF page that uses custom components.  We're trying to increase page load speed and would like to render these components asynchronously based on events (click for example) using VF remoting or something similar.  Is this possible?

Comment: If you go remoting you should just go all in with slds and roll your own html.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You can also use remoting with SLDS controllers where it's needed for FLS and CRUD. Have seen it in use by ISV's.